# Draw Inside Tool - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm using the "draw inside" tool (located at the bottom of the left sided tool bar) within illustrator.

**Basically I'm attempting to put an image inside text and its coming out choppy** (some edges aren't smoothed over and the letters are distorted). I'm using a simple San Serif - Myriad Pro.

**SEE BELOW**

[image]

I was hoping it was just a preview thing and that the final product wouldn't look like that, but I printed it out and it came out the same way - distorted and uneven.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a limitation of the tool. Worked fine for me though.

You could try manually masking it instead:

First, make a copy of your text object, put it at the top of the layer (has to be the same layer as the image is in), click the target button for the new text-object and select the container layer (by pressing the name of it not the target button). Then press the "Make/Release Clipping Mask" button in the Layers panel. See screenshot below:

[image: Image detailing how to mask image with text]

Comment: I tried what you suggested, no luck. I'm almost positive it depends on the font because I tried with Gotham and it work just fine. Thanks for the help though!!

Comment: Ok yeah, that seems likely. When is it that the problem  arises? After exporting from Illustrator or before as well?

Comment: before as well. However I noticed that the bigger the font size, the less of a problem it is.

Comment: Well, just hit me up if you run into the problem again. Seems like a nut worth cracking.